# For each course, list the students who have not taken it

Tags: database

I have a Table **schedule** with **student** and **subject** as columns

```
|student  |subject    |
|---------|-----------|
| Tina    | Math      |
| Tina    | English   |
| Sam     | Geography |
| Sam     | English   |
| Sam     | History   |
| Rafael  | English   |
|---------|-----------|
```

The output should be

```
|-----------|--------|
| Math      | Sam    |
| Math      | Rafael |
| Geography | Tina   |
| Geography | Rafael |
| History   | Tina   |
| History   | Sam    |
|-----------|--------|
```

I have tried subtracting distinct student from each row in

```
select group_concat(student)
     , subject 
  from schedule  
 group 
    by subject
```

But not successful.

Would appreciate any feedback

Comment: Why would you use group_concat?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. That's the approach I took. The alternative is join but didn't know how to proceed with that

Comment: See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wnAM7vAbWPzEu8MvWTSBqv/2

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH 
subjects AS ( SELECT DISTINCT subject 
              FROM schedule ),
students AS ( SELECT DISTINCT student 
              FROM schedule )
SELECT subject, student
FROM subjects
CROSS JOIN students
LEFT JOIN schedule USING (subject, student)
WHERE schedule.student IS NULL;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9f90008e65d2567309d081a4767b24b9)

PS. I think you have tables of students and subjects somewhere. If so then use them instead of CTEs.